# No Config prompt for RAID card

Tags: raid, dell-poweredge, hardware-raid, bios

I have a PERC 5/i in a Dell 2950 and it doesn't prompt me to enter the BIOS configuration for it, nor will it initialize. But if I take the RAM out of it, it will give me the following error

```
RAID Adapter

Memory Error !!!

Please check the SDRAM Connection
```

When I boot with the RAM installed in it just skips over where the prompt should be to enter the configuration utility for it, it doesn't acknowledge the RAID card's existence at all. It will go straight to information and a prompt for DRAC, followed by

```
no boot device available
```

none of the status indicators on the drive trays light up at all either.

would this just be a bad card? Or could it be a configuration setting I've missed somewhere?

Answer (score 0):

If you do not get any RAID Controller boot prompt (where you need to press Ctrl+R), approximately 20-25 seconds into the boot sequence, it meas the RAID adapter is either bad, disabled or incorrectly detected.

There is no reason to take the RAM out. You should try reconnecting the adapter to the server, maybe it will be detected correctly then.

After your comment, it appears that the controller is not set in the correct mode from the BIOS. If it is not set in RAID mode, the CTRL+R option will not appear. Check into that. Press  to enter the Dell Inc. PowerEdge BIOS screen.
Scroll to **SATA Settings**. Press  and **ensure that the SATA Controller is set to RAID mode**.

Comment: The reason I bring up the RAM (on the RAID card -- just want to be clear on that) is because (and correct me if I am wrong) the card shouldn't be able to give an error message on whether or not it has RAM installed if the card isn't functioning.
.
 Under integrated devices in the BIOS i have the integrated RAID card enabled. I've removed the card and reconnected it many times.

Comment: It's more clear now, I updated the answer.

Comment: So i didn't see those settings, so after an hour of trying to find a way to update the BIOS (because dell only had the update as an exe installer and there's no os on the server) I got it updated and the only settings I see related to SATA are (on the main menu) SATA port 1 and SATA port 2 both disabled and (under integrated devices) there's embedded SATA set to enabled.

Comment: The SATA options should be under something named "Embedded SATA". Is the controller listed under IRQ assignments ?

Comment: If it's not called 'Embedded' it must be under  SATA Settings/SATA Controller .

Comment: Yes Embedded SATA is set to ATA Mode I only have ATA Mode and off as options.. And they do show up in the IRQ assignments.

https://ibin.co/3BtjcwE44XBv.jpg
https://ibin.co/3BtjsY6NBXex.jpg
https://ibin.co/3Btk3myM4JFO.jpg

Comment: Turn ATA mode off and then you should have the RAID option somewhere near-by. Looks like RAID mode does not show because ATA-compatibility is on.